# RingException in guzzlehttp with message URL is invalid

Tags: php, xen, guzzle

I am using php5.6 on ubuntu 16.04.

The following code is using php sirCamp/Xenapi. The following code connects to a machine on Xen server on local intranet.

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Sircamp\Xenapi\Xen as Xen;

$ip='172.31.100.14';
$username='root';
$password='root@123';
try{
 $xen = new Xen($ip,$username,$password);
}catch(XenConnectionException $e){
    echo $e;
}

// $vm = $xen->getVMByNameLabel("centos6.7");
// echo $vm->getUUID()->getValue();
//$vm->cleanShutdown(); 
?>
```

the error it gave was

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException' with message 'Error creating resource: [message] URL is invalid: 172.31.100.14 [file] /var/www/htmt/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php [line] 403' in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php:177 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php(412): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\StreamHandler->createResource(Object(Closure), Array, Array) #1 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php(220): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\StreamHandler->createStreamResource('172.31.100.14', Array, Array, Resource id #5) #2 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php(34): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\StreamHandler->createStream('172.31.100.14', Array) #3 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RequestFsm.php(129): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\StreamHandler->__invoke(Array) #4 /var/www/html in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 51
```

The host 172.31.100.14 I am trying to connect is online and I can ssh and ping to it. But it does not work this way using php.